# Matching rows from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to copy results from another sheet based on the cell values on the active worksheet. i.e loop through every element in array ***"GWworkStations()"*** and find a match in column B of ***"Col List"*** sheet, and then copy the corresponding values in ***"C:E"*** to an array ***"MatchedEntries"*** so I can copy them back to the active sheet.

The code is returning empty for ***"matchedRow"***, instead of reporting the row number. I am not getting an error.

```
dim MatchedEntries() as string
dim GWworkStations() as variant
number_of_rows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("New Sheet")
    GWworkStations() = range("B2:B" & number_of_rows)
End With

ReDim MatchedEntries(1 To r) 'Size the array to hold the results.

'for every cell that is not empty in GWworkStations(), search through column B of 'Col List ' sheet.

For i = 1 To number_of_rows 

    'matchedRow = Empty
    On Error Resume Next 'Keep running if Excel MATCH function below doesn't find a match.
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then
        matchedRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(GWworkStations(i, 1), range("Col List!B:B"), 0)

        If matchedRow = Empty Then Debug.Print "Empty " & matchedRow

        If IsEmpty(matchedRow) Then 'No match.         
            MatchedEntries(i, 1) = "" 'GWworkStations(i, 1) 
        Else
            'If GWworkStations(i, 1) = GWworkStations(i - 1) Then

            If IsNumeric(matchedRow) Then 'Match was found.
                MatchedEntries(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(range("List!C:E"), matchedRow, 1)
            Else 'MATCH function returned a non-numeric result.
                MatchedEntries(i, 1) = ""
            End If 'IsNumeric(MatchedRow)
        End If 'IsEmpty(MatchedRow)
    Else
    End If
Next i
range("E2:G" & number_of_rows) = MatchedEntries() 'Write the tag name  results out to range E:G.
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel doesn't like the space in the sheet name. You can fix this by using single quotes: `Range("'Col List'!B:B")`, or by replacing `Range("Col List!B:B")`with `Sheets("Col List").Columns(2)`.

You could also use the `Range.Find` method (which I would prefer):

```
matchedRow = Sheets("Sheet 3").Columns(2).Find(str).Row
```

Comment: @arcadeprecint if I want to change the macro to search for multiple occurences in another sheet and copy the adjacent cells to the active sheet, what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: @Gudbahri you should post a new question for this. However, referencing different worksheets shouldn't be to difficult? You do it in your code already. Please make sure to give it your best try first. Upon looking at the code above again I have two urgent suggestions that will help you: Use `Options Explicit` (google what it means). It will help you write coherent code. Also, don't use `On Error Resume Next` or at least deactivate it after the relevant line. It's the reason you don't get error messages and very bad practice! (again, google what it means and how to use it)

Comment: I will do as you suggested, Thank you for checking.